# Openj9 version for DST 2019 brasil

Tags: openj9

We need to know the openj9 version that includes DST brasil 2019 changes (iana 2019b or Greater).

link 
https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=openj9#x64_linux
please clarify

Comment: Is this related to https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/brazil-scraps-dst.html ?  And do you know which versions of OpenJDK include this change?

Comment: Looks like Java 13.0.1 contains IANA Data 2019b.  Still need to check 8 & 11

Answer (score 1):

OpenJ9 will pick up those changes when they are available in OpenJDK releases.

The `0.17.0` release of OpenJ9 will ship

- Java 13.0.1 containing IANA Data 2019b
- Java 11 containing IANA Data 2019c, &
- Java 8 containing IANA Data 2019c

The tzdb-2019c update has the DST 2019 change for Brazil.  Not sure about the `b` version.

(With thanks to the help from the Eclipse OpenJ9 slack community)